# Proving convergent sequences are Cauchy sequences

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

> Prove that if $x_n \rightarrow a, n \rightarrow \infty$ then $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

I believe I have found the proof as follows, wondering if there are any simpler methods or added intuition. For me, it makes sense that if a sequence has a limit, then distances between elements in the sequence must be getting smaller, in order for it to converge.

Given $\epsilon > 0, \exists N_1 \ s.t. \ \forall n \geq N_1:$

$|x_n - a| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$

and for $m > n \geq N_1$ we also have:

$|x_m -a| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$

Let $N \geq N_1$, then $\forall n,m \geq N$ we have:

$|x_n-x_m| = |x_n - a -x_m+a| < |x_n - a| + |-(x_m -a)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$

Therefore $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Also, **if a sequence is Cauchy does it always converge**? In other words, is it sufficient to check if a sequence is Cauchy to check for convergence.

Comment: "if a sequence is not Cauchy can it converge?" you literally just proved if it converges it is Cauchy....

Comment: Very good proof. Indeed, if a sequence is convergent, then it is Cauchy (it can't be not Cauchy, you have just proved that!). However, the converse is not true: A space where all Cauchy sequences are convergent, is called a complete space. In complete spaces, Cauchy property is equivalent to convergence. However (for example Riemann integrable functions on $\mathbb R$, say) incomplete spaces certainly do exist, but there is an abstract notion of "completion" of a space, which is used time and again to unify these concepts.

Comment: Yes haha sorry, what I meant to ask was if a sequence is Cauchy does it always converge, which  астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг explained nicely!

Comment: It is true that a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$ converges to a member of $\Bbb R.$ This is a consequence of the definition of $\Bbb R.$ A Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb Q$ will converge in $\Bbb R$ but it may or may not converge to a member of $\Bbb Q$.  So whether a sequence is said to converge depends on the $space$ (e.g. $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb R$ ) that is  under consideration.

Comment: the title is opposed to your question

Comment: " For me, it makes sense that if a sequence has a limit, then distances between elements in the sequence must be getting smaller,"  One needs to be careful about what you mean "distance between terms".  What does that mean?  Distances between *which* terms.  Note $a_1 = 1$ and $a_{n} = a_{n-1} + \frac 1n$ is not Cauchy and does not converge although one can say the "distance between terms gets smaller".  Oh, and also "getting smaller" doesn't mean approaching zero.  $a_{n} = a_n + 1 +\frac 1n$ then distance between terms is getting smaller but its always more than $1$.

Comment: In a "complete" space or one with the least upper bound property then Cauchy sequences must converge.  But not all spaces are complete.  $\mathbb Q$ is not.  But $\mathbb R$ is.

Comment: Also, **if a sequence is Cauchy does it always converge**? $\rightarrow$ (see Banach spaces), i.e. in the open interval (0,1) 1/n is a Cauchy sequence but it does not converge.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that a Cauchy sequence is convergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132993/prove-that-a-cauchy-sequence-is-convergent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

Secondly,  the property of having every Cauchy sequence converge is very important,  and is known as *completeness*.

As an example,  $\mathbb R $ with the usual metric is complete.

Another important area of study is *Banach spaces*, which roughly are complete metric spaces where the metric comes from a norm.

More generally,  there are *Hilbert spaces*, which are equipped with an inner product.

Answer (score 0):

With response to the comments above, it is not always true that a Cauchy sequence is convergent. For example, if we think of metric spaces, 
yes it is true that any Cauchy sequence in $(R, \mathrm{d}E)$ is convergent and any Cauchy sequence in $(X, \mathrm{d}\delta)$ is eventually constant, so convergent.  We have the counter example however:  Cauchy does not imply convergent in $(0, \infty)$, $d(x, y) = |x − y|$.

Comment: I guess I should have clarified. This is for metric spaces.

Comment: It's not true for all metric spaces.  $\mathbb Q$ with the normal metric is a metric space where it is not true.

Comment: Or try $\Bbb R-\{0\}$.