# A proof I was studying created a Cauchy sequence without proving it.

Tags: cauchy-sequences

I will first give some context for my question to be as defined as possible.

Prove that a projection onto the set K: $P_K(v) = \text{argmin}_{w \in K}||v-w||$ exists and is unique. Without lose of generality assume that the vector $v$ is always $0$ (Because translation does not modify the convergence of K).

Assumptions of the proof:

- Hilbert space.
- K is convex subset.

The proof started with the parallelogram law and reached this formula (I skipped some steps but assume that this formula is correct. I can expand it if requested):

- Let $w \in K, d = min||v- w||= min ||0-w|| = min ||w||$
  $$u, w \in K, ||u-w||^2 \le 2||u||^2 + 2||w||^2-4d^2$$

Then the proof moved to showing that such projection $P_K(v)$ exists. In order to do so they defined the following Cauchy sequence of elements in K:

- Let $\{V_n\} \subset K $ be a minimizing sequence.
- $||V_n|| \to d$ when $n \to \infty$

At this point is where my question starts. Their next step is to show that the sequence indeed converges to $d$. But in a previous exercise I had to prove that something was a Cauchy sequence (CS) to begin with, how can we already asume that a definition of a sequence that we made up is a CS without proving it?

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 1):

They do prove it's a CS although it may not be obvious: they show it converges to $d$. So in particular it converges - which implies that it's a Cauchy sequence.

Edit: Here's a discussion with proof that [Convergent $\implies$ Cauchy.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2818650/convergent-implies-cauchy)